# Ruby Layout/SpaceAroundOperators: Surrounding space missing for operator &

Tags: ruby

I originally had the following code:

```
Parallel.map(arr) { |f| f.call }
```

But Rubocop said to change it to:

```
Parallel.map(arr) &:call
```

However, Rubocop is now reporting:

```
Layout/SpaceAroundOperators: Surrounding space missing for operator &
```

This is giving me `undefined method &`:

```
Parallel.map(arr) & :call
```

This doesn't work either:

```
Parallel.map(arr)(&:call)
```

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: I highly doubt Rubocop told you to change the code to `Parallel.map(arr) &:call`. I am betting you 1000$ that it told you to change the code to `Parallel.map(arr, &:call)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it as second argument (it converts to block)

```
Parallel.map(arr, &:call)
```